# Pager information in services_views json response

Tags: views, services, paging

Is there a suggested mechanism for retrieving pagination/pager information in a JSON response in a services_views configuration? I thought enabling the pager would give me something, but it does not. The only way seems to be for me to hard-code the pagination into the module, which seems very unsustainable.

Is there a more preferred solution for for ajax calls that need to know the total number of results in the view?

Below is what I've got so far (patch against services_views.resource.inc):

```
---- sites/all/modules/contrib/services_views/services_views.resource.inc -----
index 9aeeb1b..24b948f 100755
@@ -27,6 +27,10 @@
  */
 function services_views_retrieve($view_name, $display_id = 'default', $args = array(), $offset = 0, $limit = 10, $return_type = FALSE, $filters = array()) {
   $result = array();
+
+  // Added by SR 201212031623
+  $total_rows = _get_view_total_rows($view_name, $display_id, $args, $filters);
+  
   $view = views_get_view($view_name);

   // Put all arguments and filters and then execute.
@@ -70,6 +74,10 @@ function services_views_retrieve($view_name, $display_id = 'default', $args = ar
       $items = array();
       foreach ($view->result as $row) {
         $item = new stdClass();
+
+        // Added by SR 201212031623
+        _set_total_rows(&$item, $total_rows);
+
         foreach ($view->field as $field_id => $field) {
           if (!empty($field->options['label'])) {
             $field_label = strtolower($field->options['label']);
@@ -177,3 +185,34 @@ function services_views_execute_view($view_info, $view = NULL, $display_id = NUL
   $view->destroy();
   return $output;
 }
+
+
+
+/**
+ * Get the total number of results prior to applying offset
+ *   Added by SR 201212031623
+ */
+function _get_view_total_rows($view_name, $display_id, $args, $filters) {
+  // Statistics and counts
+
+  $view_stat = views_get_view($view_name);
+  $view_stat->set_display($display_id);
+  $view_stat->set_arguments($args, FALSE);
+  $view_stat->set_exposed_input($filters);
+  $view_stat->pre_execute();
+  $view_stat->execute();
+  $total_rows = $view_stat->total_rows;
+
+  return $total_rows;
+
+}
+ 
+/**
+ * Set the total number of results into the items object
+ *   Added by SR 201212031623
+ */
+function _set_total_rows(&$item, $total_rows) {
+  // Add stats into each row if requested
+  $total_rows_label = "_total_rows";
+  $item->$total_rows_label = $total_rows;
+}
```